# How to tune hyperparamters and use CalibratedClassifierCV correctly

Tags: probability, classification, scikit-learn, calibration, tuning

Let's say that I have a classifier C ( for example a random forest classifier) and a Dataset.

From what I understand I can:

1. prefit the classifier on a portion of data and then "calibrate it" on the other portion.
2. use the method option to fit both the classifier and the regressor (calibrator) using a CV approach.

I have then two questions about how should i act with respect to hyperparamter tuning in this setting:

1. should I tune the hyperparameters, for example with a gridsearchCV, on the "first" portion of data (using CV), then retrain it on the whole first portion and finally tune the calibrator on the part I kept away?
2. IN this case, how should i tune the hyperparamter? Should Ii tune them on the whole dataset and then feed the ones I found to the model I pass to the CalibratedClassifierCV?

Comment: Are you wanting to build both a classifier and a regressor? If so, how does the regressor relate to the classifier you want to calibrate?

Comment: @Lynn by regressor i meant the calibrator (that is in fact a regressor).

Comment: So then please edit to clarify the text!

Comment: Done. honestly, i thought that using the naming convention by sources by sklearn would be clearer.